# awk not giving output

Tags: bash, unix, awk

```
7369|SMITH     |CLERK    |    7902|17-DEC-80|       800|          |        20               
7499|ALLEN     |SALESMAN |    7698|20-FEB-81|      1600|       300|        30               
7521|WARD      |SALESMAN |    7698|22-FEB-81|      1250|       500|        30               
7566|JONES     |MANAGER  |    7839|02-APR-81|      2975|          |        20               
7654|MARTIN    |SALESMAN |    7698|28-SEP-81|      1250|      1400|        30               
7698|BLAKE     |MANAGER  |    7839|01-MAY-81|      2850|          |        30               
7782|CLARK     |MANAGER  |    7839|09-JUN-81|      2450|          |        10               
7788|SCOTT     |ANALYST  |    7566|19-APR-87|      3000|          |        20               
7839|KING      |PRESIDENT|        |17-NOV-81|      5000|          |        10               
7844|TURNER    |SALESMAN |    7698|08-SEP-81|      1500|         0|        30               
7876|ADAMS     |CLERK    |    7788|23-MAY-87|      1100|          |        20               
7900|JAMES     |CLERK    |    7698|03-DEC-81|       950|          |        30               
7902|FORD      |ANALYST  |    7566|03-DEC-81|      3000|          |        20               
7934|MILLER    |CLERK    |    7782|23-JAN-82|      1300|          |        10
```

`awk '$4== "7698"'` not giving anything in output...???

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot `awk -F '\|'` but your lines also seem to contain whitespace.

Comment: Note that `\|` is the same as `|` awk parses FS twice and in this case will report something like `awk: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|'`. If you want to use a regex, and get rid of the spaces, something like ` awk -F' *\\| *'` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `regex` match instead of exact match to eliminate space issues. Also supply proper field separator `|`.

```
awk -F'\|' '$4~/7698/' file
```